# How can I create a datatable of my 3 select SQL statements

Tags: ado.net

I have a database with one table and I have 3 select SQL statement.

Those select items have different conditions. How can I merge the answer of this 3 SQL command?

I don't want to merge them, rows by rows to a data table. Is there any other way?

Some thing like this..

```
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top "+ cont0 +" * from (select * from db where tablenumber=0)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapt=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
        adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top "+ cont1 +" * from (select * from db where tablenumber=1)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
        adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapt.Fill(dttemp);
        foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }
        if (cont2 != 0)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top " + cont2 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=2)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
            adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            dttemp = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dttemp);
            foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
        }
        if (cont3 != 0)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top " + cont3 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=3)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
            adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            dttemp = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dttemp);
            foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
        }
        if (cont4 != 0)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top " + cont4 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=4)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
            adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            dttemp = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dttemp);
            foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
        }
        if (cont5 != 0)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top " + cont5 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=5)  order by ID ASC", mycon);
            adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            dttemp = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dttemp);
            foreach (DataRow row in dttemp.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying you don't have a database? How, where and when do you want to create it? What kind of database should it be? Should the software be able to auto-create it on the fly, or is it just one time? Please edit the question and add relevant information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. Thanks.

Comment: i have a database with one table and i have 3 select sql statement those select items with different condition, how can i merge the answer of this 3 sql command? i don't want to merge them, rows by rows to a datatable. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them simply like this:

```
"select * from
    (select *, row_number() over(partition by field order by id) as rn 
     from table1 where field in(0, 5, 9)) t 
 where rn <= " + cont
```

**EDIT:**

```
string command = "select * from ( select top "+ cont0 +" * from db where tablenumber=0 order by ID) t union all 
                  select * from ( select top "+ cont1 +" * from db where tablenumber=1 order by ID) t";

if (cont2 != 0)
    comand += " union all select * from ( select top " + cont2 + " * from db where tablenumber=2 order by ID) t";

if (cont3 != 0)
    comand += " union all select * from ( select top " + cont3 + " * from db where tablenumber=3 order by ID) t";

....

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, mycon);
OleDbDataAdapter adapt=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
....
```

Comment: but my sql command is a little different. my sql command is : select top"+ cont +"* from (select * from db where tablenumber="+mychoose+")  order by ID ASC

Comment: Then add thatt information to your question. Did you think we would guess that you have top??

Comment: @AfshinEzadi, see edits. In the future provide with actual statements.

Comment: where is the where condition,
select top " + cont1 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=1)  order by ID ASC;;;;;;

select top " + cont2 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=2)  
order by ID ASC;;;;;;
select top " + cont3 + " * from (select * from db where tablenumber=3)  order by ID ASC;;;;
cont and tablenumber filed are dynamic, how to change this 3 sql statement to a 1 sql query, really sorry for my bad english